# Bitcoin prices from exchanges

Tags: exchange-rate

I’m stuck between finding an api that lets me get bitcoin prices from different exchanges, I found coincap.io but they don’t seem to give me all the necessary data I require.

Please if anybody knows how I can go about this should kindly furnish me with the resources needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/

They have different pricing tiers for the services they offer, but some of the services are free. They have a range of exchanges from which you can get the data.

Comment: Yeah, found them too. I’m looking searching to see if I can get more for variety purposes.